# Keystone service in OpenStack consumes a lot of CPU

Tags: openstack-keystone

My problem is that keystone consumes 10% of the CPU when idle. In the keystone logs I saw that these messages were arriving approximately twice per second.

[Keystone logs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DPKBK.png)

Is this CPU consumption normal? If not, how can this be fixed?